# Black graphics glitch on CentOS7 GNOME

Tags: gnome, gui, graphics, intel-graphics

**ISSUE** - Every so often any dialog box, newly opened window, etc will be black. I do not know the exact cause. I notice at times opening PDFs or using Tab Groups on Firefox (latest ESR) will do the trick. Not always though. The only fix is to reboot my computer, until it happens again. **I am not sure what the exact cause is, and therefore, and unable to reproduce it easily.**

The following screen shot shows what is happening. The black window was newly opened from Pidgin.

[image: black-graphics-glitch-centos7]

Some important specs:

- CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
- Linux 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64
- gnome-session 3.8.4
- Processor: Intel Core2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz × 2
- Memory: 3.0GB
- Desktop Dell Vostro 200
- Graphics card: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller, using the `intel` driver.

Comment: Try switching from the hardware compositor to the software compositor.

Comment: @SteveWills could you share a link on how to do that for centos?

Comment: Under System Settings -> Graphics Forced Fallback Mode on

Comment: I do not have a "Graphics" option under "Settings".

Comment: Perhaps:gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name gnome-fallback